# Allowing SSH through iptables

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have a remote server that I can access with SSH.

The first time, what I did was:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.80.55 --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Now I have only a single port accessible from a single IP and everything is locked.

How can I unblock all the traffic (at least for SSH)?

Comment: An iptables -F will flush everything. Then make sure you allow SSH access first. This assuming you still have console access to the machine itself.

Comment: It would be easier to set your INPUT chain policy to drop. Allow then ssh traffic and that on `9043`  No need for the `-j DROP` rule anymore

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are the only two rules you entered, if you want to have unrestricted access to all ports, just do:

```
# make default policy ACCEPT so that you don't block out yourself,
/usr/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
# remove all rules (flush)
/usr/sbin/iptables -F
```

make sure nothing else blocks you here (like default policy DROP for OUTPUT)

If you want to keep all others ports blocked, and just have ssh world-wide open, do this instead:

```
# insert new rule (in the beginning of the list) before that accepts ssh traffic 
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
# remove previously added rule (no longer needed)
/usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.80.55 --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
```